# Jquery is getting the incorrect difference between now and a future date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I tried to code a counter. For the first value it should show the difference between today and a future date. Out of some reason its showing an complete wrong difference. Do you know why?

The set future date 2th october 2020 should output a difference of 15 days and not over 40.

```js
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2020, 10, 02);
const secondDate = new Date();
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
jQuery('#reducedaily').text(diffDays);

jQuery('.count, .count2').each(function () {
  jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: jQuery(this).text()
  }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('count')){
          jQuery(this).text(now.toFixed(0));
        }
        else{
          jQuery(this).text(now.toFixed(1));
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="counterbackground" class="shadow">
<div class="counterdiv"><span class="count countervalue" id="reducedaily">239</span><br> <span class="counterdescription">Tage bis zum Event<br> (2.10.2020)</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`, the rounding value is going one day up

Comment: Can you describe the specific problem, e.g. what number are you expecting in the count? Also you have included a lot of code that isn't related to the problem. Creating a [MRE] with just the code that shows the problem makes it much easier for us to help :)

Comment: Ive edited the code to be more minimalistic and described the problem better now

Comment: Unless you're using the jQuery UI Datepicker, `Date` objects have nothing to do with jQuery. They're vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the "month" parameter in the `Date` function in your jQuery, **months are 0-indexed** so they start at 0 instead of 1 as you might expect. So when you pass in `10`, that actually represents November instead of October - this is why you got 30 extra days than you expected.

There are many ways to specify the date (see [MDN Web Docs for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). For example any of these will create a date object for 02 October 2020:

```
firstDate = new Date(2020, 09, 02);     // when using the month param, it is (month-1)
firstDate = new Date("2020-10-02");     // note you DO use "10" in a date string
firstDate = new Date("10/02/2020");     // note mm/dd/yyyy format
firstDate = new Date("2 October 2020"); // or you can use text
```

**Working Example with your code**

```js
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2020, 09, 02);
const secondDate = new Date();
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
jQuery('#reducedaily').text(diffDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counterdiv"><span class="count countervalue" id="reducedaily">239</span><br> <span class="counterdescription">Tage bis zum Event<br>(2.10.2020)</span></div>
```

**Working Example to test date strings**

```js
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const secondDate = new Date();

$("#testdate").on("click", function() {
   dateStr = $("#date_to_check").val(); 
   showDate(dateStr, "days_left");
});

   
showDate("2020-10-02", "days_left_test");
showDate("10/02/2020", "days_left_test");
showDate("2 October 2020", "days_left_test");
showDate("October 02 2020", "days_left_test");

function showDate(dateStr, elid){
    document.getElementById(elid).innerHTML += "Date: <b>"+dateStr+" </b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Days left: <b>"+ Math.round(Math.abs((new Date(dateStr) - secondDate) / oneDay))+"</b><br>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Test a date:</p>
<input type="text" id="date_to_check" placeholder="Enter date string">
<button id="testdate">Test</button>
<div id="days_left" style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>

<p><b>More date Tests:</b></p>
<div id="days_left_test"></div>
```

Comment: @RobG Yes, and I link to the documentation that explains that. That sentence is in reference to the Date function that they call in the jQuery code (as thats what they specifically asked about) rather than the Date function being part of jQuery. I see how it could be read either way though - one of those foibles of the English language - so I'll edit the text to clarify that.